# Select multiple columns within a certain range of another column

Tags: python, numpy

```
1   0   0       0.579322 
2   0   0       0.579306 
3   0   0       0.279274
4   5   0       0.579224
5   3   0       0.579157 
3   0   0       0.47907
7   0   1       0.378963
8   9   0       0.578833
```

I'm a beginner in python and struggling to do this. I have four columns like above mentioned, I need to save 1,2,3 columns which have the value greater than 0.4 and less than 0.5 in column 4. Can this be done via numpy? 
This is the code I tried.

```
import csv

csv_out = csv.writer(open('data_new.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')

f = open('coordiantes.txt',"w+")
for line in f:
 vals = line.split('\t')
  for vals ([3]>=0.4 & vals[3]<=0.5):
   print vals[0],vals[1],vals[2]
csv_out.writerow(vals[0], vals[1], vals[2],vals[3])
f.close()
```

Comment: yes you can, but what did you try ? (show us your code, don't be shy ;) )

Comment: the code above is a mess, that possibly you posted w/o any testing — I doubly appreciate, in particular, `open('coordiantes.txt',"w+")` because it truncates the file and the file name seems a bit inconspicuous.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with a few built in numpy functions

```
vals = #your array

#do a Boolean index of your array where the fourth column meets your criteria
vals = vals[np.where((vals[:,3] <=0.5)&(vals[:,3]>0.4))]

#use numpy to slice off last column and  to save the file
np.savetxt('coordiantes.txt',vals[:,:3],delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('coordinates.txt')
idx = np.where((data[:,3] <= 0.5) & (data[:,3] > 0.4))[0] # save where col 4's data is in (0.4,0.5]
selected_data = data[idx,:3] # get the 1st three cols for the rows of interest
np.savetxt('data_new.csv', selected_data, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thanks. but looks like this does not work with csv file format.